# Best way to speed up search result display

Tags: php, mysql, performance, search, lucene

We've been prototyping a search results system for a mySQL database with about 2 million names and addresses and 3 million associated subscription and conference attendance records.

At the moment the search is executed and all results returned - for each result I then execute a second query to look up subscriptions / conferences for the person's unique ID. I've got indexes on all the important columns and the individual queries execute quite quickly in phpMyAdmin (0.0xxx seconds) but feed this into a webpage to display (PHP, paged using DataTables) and the page takes seconds to render. We've tried porting the data to a Lucene database and it's like LIGHTNING but the bottleneck still seems to be displayng the results rather than retrieving them.

I guess this would be due to the overhead of building, serving and rendering the page in browser. I think I can remove the subquery I mention above by doing GROUP_CONCAT to get the subscription codes in the original query, but how can I speed up the display of the page with the results on?

I'm thinking little and often querying with AJAX / server side paging might be the way to go here (maybe get 50 results, the query is smaller, the page is smaller and can be served quicker) but I welcome any suggestions you guys might have.

Comment: Can you provide any sql samples / EXPLAIN's / schema information including indexes?  Chances are that second query is limiting you as the milliseconds soon add up.

Comment: Have you tried rendering it without "DataTables"

Comment: @Simonatmso.net - here's an example query of searching for someone by name: http://pastebin.com/DWscK2Y4 - there's a lot more in that subscription find query than there needs to be because the same query is used elsewhere in the system. Might write a separate smaller version for search results only.

Comment: @Rob I have - there doesn't seem much difference. I suppose the page is still being returned in it's entireity, we just don't have DataTables then paging it for us.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on some of my reports its purely down to the webbrowser processing the seer amount of html returned.  As mentioned below server side paging is the solution so limit to say 50 returned results per page or so.  Downside is it results in hundreds of pages for lage data sets.  The alternative I've been doing is generating the HTML but not rendering/outputting to screen.  Instead I've been writing it out to a PDF then storing the pdf on the file system and making the PDF available to the user.  This has high initial load but also allows me to recall results in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you are using pagination with Datatables, all the results are loaded into the page source code at first although you are using the [server side feature.](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html)

Loading 2 million rows at once will always render slowly. You have to go for server side pagination, it can be by AJAX or by a normal PHP script.

You can also consider using a cache system to speed up the loading of data from the server and avoiding calling the database when it is not needed. If your data can be changing randomly in time, you can always use a function to check whether or not the data has changed since the last time you cached the data and if so, updating the cached data.

Comment: Something like searching a view, perhaps, and syncing that view at random? I'm not returning all 2 million rows every time but it is true that the result counts can run into five figures.... which is a lot of data for the server to be rendering to the browser at once. The more I think about this the more obvious it seems that smaller results are the immediate improvement....

Comment: Just take as an example any big website around there. None of them load that amount of data at once. Pagination and sorting by server side and autocomplete searches by AJAX, if not, by POST.

Comment: True. Any recommendations for a caching system that could do the trick? I already pondered on whether a mySQL View, occasionally refreshed (new records are added every few minutes, updates less frequent - realtime isn't VITALLY important) might be better for this - your thoughts?

Comment: Its not a server side issue its a browser issue.

Comment: You can read about PHP caching in some sites, for example [this](http://www.xeweb.net/2010/01/15/simple-php-caching/) or [this](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php). I have only worked with CakePHP framework and its cache so Im not very familiar with other techniques.